# Как воспроизвести файлы mp3; wav; ogg?

Tags: mp3, wav, ogg

Как воспроизвести файлы mp3; wav; ogg? В меню pycharm эти файлы со знаком вопроса. И при запуске пишет, что не находит их. Библиотеки все стоят для этого.Что нужно установить для активации этих файлов? У меня стоит Linux Mint.

Comment: Для воспроизведения этих файлов нужен аудиоплеер. Что конкретно вы хотите сделать с этими файлами в Pycharm? `Библиотеки все стоят для этого` - какие конкретно библиотеки, для чего "для этого"?

Comment: Вообще, Pycharm не обязан знать обо всех существующих типах файлов. Тем более об аудиофайлах, т.к. он не предназначен для работы с ними (хотя ваша программа может работать с этими файлами, при наличии необходимых библиотек). Никакой активации аудиофайлов в Pycharm не нужно.

Comment: Есть будильник с таймером, должен сработать звук, а он не срабатывает. Вот кусочек кода в котором проблема: music = pyglet.resource.media('music.mp3') и еще: /home/vladimir1956/PycharmProjects/vlad56/newpython/./music.mp3 Error code: -1094995529

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в сам вопрос (нажмите "править" под вопросом, чтобы отредактировать его). Возможно не находит файл. Нужно в настройках запуска проекта посмотреть рабочую директорию проекта (Working directory) и указать путь к mp3 файлу относительно этой директории.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.

Comment: Прописал вот такой путь: music = ("/home/vladimir1956/PycharmProjects/vlad56/alarm.wav") а вот ответ: pyglet.media.codecs.ffmpeg.FFmpegException: avformat_open_input in ffmpeg_open_filename returned an error opening file /home/vladimir1956/PycharmProjects/vlad56/alarm.wav Error code: -1094995529

Comment: Попробуйте через pyglet.media.load загружать, см: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/media.html#loading-media

Comment: Для загрузки через pyglet.resource.media вроде как нужен модуль `__main__.py`, рядом с ним будут искаться ресурсы, либо нужно вручную указать папку ресурсов, см.: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/resources.html#specifying-the-resource-path

Comment: Как то всё запутано?! С картинками проще, их поставил в меню и они тут же открываются. А вот аудио файлами просто беда! Они как бы по логике, если есть библиотеки тоже должны проигрывать, не хотят.

Comment: Тут не могу ничего сказать. Нужно параллельно смотреть документацию и экспериментировать.

Comment: Когда в pycharm я открываю файл alarm.wav, то в открывшемся окне он показывает в разделе Register new file Type Association, в подразделе Open matching files in PyCharm: иконка с названием Text. поэтому наверное файл и не запускается. Что нужно сделать, чтобы это исправить?

Comment: Никак не исправлять, не нужно аудифайлы никак регистрировать. "Регистрация" нужна только для подсветки кода в текстовых файлах. То что PyCharm не умеет сам работать с аудиофайлами никак не связано с тем, что ваша программа не может аудиофайл открыть.